# my value property doesn't pass me anything

Tags: javascript, html, null

I'm trying to simply get the value of an input and put it into a p tag.but it looks like that I'm not getting anything from the input tag

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <button class="button" onclick="sum();">click</button>
    <p id="lblResult">Result</p>
</body>

<script>
    const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    function sum()
    {
       document.getElementById('lblREsult').innerHTML = text;
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: put your `const` IN the function .. Or make it global with `const window.text =`

Comment: You have an typo, `lblREsult` !== `lblResult`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get value from input on page load when it's empty, move `document.getElementById('text').value` into `sum` function.

And you have an typo, `lblREsult` !== `lblResult`

```js
function sum() {
  const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<button class="button" onclick="sum();">click</button>
<p id="lblResult">Result</p>
```